# Notice: Array to string conversion with date

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database, localhost

My code is :

```
        $connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","abroadjobs"); 

        if(!$connection)
        {
            die("connection failed:".mysqli_connect_error());
        }

        $query = "SELECT * FROM interface_jobs"; 
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

        echo "<table border='1' align='center'>
        <tr><td>Reference Number</td><td>Company Name</td><td>country</td><td>Position</td><td>Salary</td><td>Open Date</td><td>Close Date</td></tr>"; 

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        echo "<tr><td>" . $row['refNumber'] . "</td><td>" . $row['comName'] . "</td><td>".$row['country']."</td><td>".$row['position']."</td><td>".$row['salary']."</td><td>".['openDate']."</td><td>".['closeDate']."</td></tr>";  
            }
        }   

        echo "</table>"; 

        mysqli_close($connection); 

        ?>
```

My error is Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\wamp64\www\oxygen\jobs.php on line 155. Line 155 is

> echo "" . $row['refNumber'] . "" . $row['comName'] . "".$row['country']."".$row['position']."".$row['salary']."".['openDate']."".['closeDate']."";

openDate and closeDate are arrays. How can I write the code correctly, without getting any errors?

Comment: Shouldn't they be `$row['openDate']` and `$row['closeDate']` instead of `['openDate']`/`['closeDate']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not valid in your case

```
"</td><td>".['openDate']."</td><td>".['closeDate']."</td></tr>"; 
                 ^                       ^
              Here                      Here
```

You need

```
"</td><td>".$row['openDate']."</td><td>".$row['closeDate']."</td></tr>";
```

> Notice: Array to string conversion with date

You can reproduce like this, for example:

```
$ php -r '$t=array("test"=>1);echo ["test"];'
PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in Command line code on line 1
Array

$ php -r '$t=array("test"=>1);echo $t["test"];'
1
```